# Java app that trys to find phrases using Regex and to display those phrases it has found

Tags: java, regex

Hy,

I have an app that trys to find phrases. My assumption that phrases begin with uppercase and end with an dot, and between can contain anything.

Bellow is my code:

```
for(String s: manyLines)
                    {
                        Pattern pa = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{1})(.*)(\\.)");
                        Matcher ma = pa.matcher(s);
                        if(ma.find())
                        {
                        manyPhrase.add(s);
            }
```

But the regex seems not to work because manyPhrase (ArryList of Strings) it gets all lines instead of just phrases.

For example, my input file has:

> Fox fox runs to escape dog dog. ak; Rabbit rabbit runs to escape fox
>   fox. 123.5, Carrot waits for rabbit rabbit in the field to return.
>   more than expected

and it should return

> Fox fox runs to escape dog dog. Rabbit rabbit runs to escape fox fox. 
>   Carrot waits for rabbit rabbit in the field to return.

Sincerly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.*
```

is greedy and is matching everything until the final period.

Try either a non-greedy matcher

```
[A-Z].*?\\.
```

or, better, use the more precise "capital letter, non-period, period" regex:

```
[A-Z][^.]*\\.
```

Lastly, if you use `()`s for grouping, it's better to use `(?:)` as non-capture groups unless you really want to store the results of the subexpressions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[A-Z].+?\\.`

This will match any upper case letter, followed by any other characters, until it finds the . character. By using the ? in our regex, we create what's known as a lazy match (i.e., it will stop as soon as the next bit is found.)

The problem with yours is the `.*`. This is a greedy match, so it will try to match as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is your assumption on what `.*` does. It doesn't know to keep looking  for everything before the period. What you want to look for is any character which isn't a period(`[^.]`), happening zero or more times (`*`). If you were to just use `.*` it would continue on to the end and include the last period.

Try this instead as your regex pattern if you want the groupings (the parens):

```
([A-Z]{1})([^.]*)\\.
```

Try this instead as your regex pattern if you just want to match:

```
[A-Z]{1}[^.]*\\.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that the `.` is *not* part of the allowed characters inside the phrase:

```
([A-Z^]{1})([^.]*)(\\.)
```

The matching is greedy and will select as many characters as possible that will match your expression.

Comment: To use it in a Java string the backslash has to be doubled. I fixed it. This is the same as your expression with a *no periods in the phrase allowed* restriction added. `[^.]*` means any characters that are not `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Full code to replace:

```
    for(String s: manyLines)
                    {
                        Pattern pa = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][^\\.]*\\.)");
                        Matcher ma = pa.matcher(s);
                        if(ma.find())
                        {
                            String correct = ma.group(0);
                        manyPhrase.add(correct);
            }
                    }
```

Use group method in order to add a substring.

Good luck,